# Directus incorrectly returns 403 Forbidden

Tags: php, api, curl, directus

I have Directus installed on a server and also locally.

The version installed on the server will frequently return `403` "Forbidden" when I attempt to do certain updates (requiring me to resort to updating the DB directly).
I've also just come across an issue where the API is returning `403`, but running the same query on my local database succeeds.

My local directus database is an exact copy of the one on my server, but it does not get these `403` issues.

**What causes Directus to incorrectly return `403` "Frobidden" on some servers?**

Comment: Heya! Do the actual php files have the right permissions setup for the server user to execute the files? Are the .htaccess files correctly setup on the server?

Answer (score 0):

I was using Quasar for admin panel and Nuxt for frontend I also faced the same problem.There is a issue with Directus patch in the core modules.I used post method which is already included in the core of directus.So I created an another endpoint and used JS SDK Code to resolve this problem.